# Optimizing bottlenecked thread safe code wrapped with unsafe thread code

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, locking

I have the following pseudocode which I want to optimize:

> (1) Lock(L1);
>
> {    Not thread-safe code  }
>
> {    Thread safe bottleneck code  }
>
> {    Not thread-safe code  }
>
> (2) Unlock(L1);

I am looking for a way to optimize the code, such that the safe bottleneck code will be performed in parallel.

Not a good idea I had:

> (1) Lock(L1);
> {    Not thread-safe code  }
>
> Unlock(L1);
>
> {    Thread safe bottleneck code  }
>
> Lock(L1);
>
> {    Not thread-safe code  }
>
> (2) Unlock(L1);

The way I see it, the lock at (1) must be unlocked before entering the thread-safe code, but if I do that there's always some edge case that causes a race condition.

I can add as many locks as I want, but prefer not to remove the lock and unlock at (1) and (2), unless there's no other option.

Assume each of the blocks are atomic and cannot be splitted.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: If the solution you provided does not work, then this likely means the order of the two "Not thread-safe code" matters and the block must not be split. If so, then this means you cannot execute "Thread safe bottleneck code" in parallel. Thus, I think what you want is simply inconsistent. Please tell us more about what the code does. Regarding the *dependencies*, there are ways to possibly execute things in parallel. Without more information, it is impossible to give a correct safe answer.

Comment: Put it shortly : if the statement "*each of the blocks are atomic and cannot be splitted*" is true, then you cannot execute "*Thread safe bottleneck code*" in parallel. This can be mathematically proven. Try to draw all possible scheduling with two threads to understand why ;) .

Comment: @JérômeRichard Not sure I understand why is that true. even if the order matters, the thread-safe block will be always executed after the first block and before the third block.

Comment: If the order matter and no thread can execute the block 1 and 3 between the block 1 and 3 of another thread, then you get a mutual exclusion where the only possible scheduling consist in executing the block 1 2 and 3 on the same thread in one exclusive block.

Comment: If this is not obvious to you, I strongly advise you to try to find *just one scheduling* where the block 2 can be parallel. If you find one, then please add it in the question : it will help us to better understand the use-case (I may have missed something important); but if you cannot find any scheduling, then it will experimentally show that this is not possible and a mutual exclusion is the best you can do in this case. In all cases, this helps.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Block 2 can be done in parallel (with the second pseudocode) when 2 threads reach there after finishing the second block - thread #1 finish the 1st block and unlocks the mutex, 2nd thread finish the 1st blocks and also enters the 2nd block

Comment: I am confused because you said that the second pseudocode has a race condition, so it should not be used. Isn't the fact that thread 2 execute the fist block between the block 1 and 3 of the thread 1 supposed to be the root of the race condition? If so, what is supposed to cause it? Why the second code is not fine precisely? If you need a specific order for the second code, you could use wait conditions, but I think the problem has to be clarified before trying to find any solution.